# How to init an MKPlacemark with a subThoroughfare property?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

In my app I'm creating my own placemarks and I need the street number separate from the street name. But I can't see how I can init an `MKPlacemark` with an address dictionary so that the street number is returned in the subThoroughfare property because there isn't a separate `ABPerson` constant for street number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to subclass MKPlacemark and override the address properties to recognise a custom set of address dictionary keys to match each of the properties.

Assuming the custom placemark class is named `CustomPlacemark`, here are the main bits of code to define the new keys for the `addressDictionary` and override the property methods.

in CustomPlacemark.h

```
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressThoroughfareKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubThoroughfareKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressLocalityKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubLocalityKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressAdministrativeAreaKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubAdministrativeAreaKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressPostalCodeKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryKey;
extern NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryCodeKey;
```

in CustomPlacemark.m

```
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressThoroughfareKey = @"thoroughfare";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubThoroughfareKey = @"subThoroughfare";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressLocalityKey = @"locality";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubLocalityKey = @"subLocality";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressAdministrativeAreaKey = @"administrativeArea";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubAdministrativeAreaKey = @"subAdministrativeArea";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressPostalCodeKey = @"postalCode";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryKey = @"country";
NSString * const kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryCodeKey = @"countryCode";

- (NSString *)thoroughfare
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressThoroughfareKey];
}

- (NSString *)subThoroughfare
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubThoroughfareKey];
}

- (NSString *)locality
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressLocalityKey];
}

- (NSString *)subLocality
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubLocalityKey];
}

- (NSString *)administrativeArea
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressAdministrativeAreaKey];
}

- (NSString *)subAdministrativeArea
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressSubAdministrativeAreaKey];
}

- (NSString *)postalCode
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressPostalCodeKey];
}

- (NSString *)country
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryKey];    
}

- (NSString *)countryCode
{
    return [self.addressDictionary objectForKey:kCustomPlacemarkAddressCountryCodeKey];
}
```